# Sharing data between event handlers?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm in a situation where I'd like to send a an object out to multiple even handlers, but have certain ones use data produced by other handlers. This sounds pretty unclear - reading it myself I don't think I'd get what I was talking about - so I'll give an example.

Let's say I've got the following:

```
interface ChangeListener
{
   public add_change(Change)
   // ...
}

class ListenerA implements ChangeListener{...}
class ListenerB implements ChangeListener{...}
```

and where the actual logic is taking place:

```
List changes = ... // populated from somewhere else
List handlers = [new ListenerA(), new ListenerB()]

foreach(change in changes)
  foreach(handler in handlers)
    handler.add_change(change)
```

My problem is that part of what ListenerA will do is create a URL for the change, and I'd like ListenerB to have access to that URL (so it can use it). As a specific example, ListenerA could use a blogging API to create a post on the change, and ListenerB could then send an email with that URL.

One option would be to have ListenerA add a property to the Change object with the newly-created URL, but I'm not sure I like mucking about with the object. Another would be to simply call them in order and pass in a value (as opposed to looping through them), but I'm trying to keep a clean separation of concerns between this part (which sends out the changes) and the listeners who try and figure out how to deal with them - so that in the future all it would take to add a ListenerC would be adding an object to the `handlers` list.

Any ideas on a best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is Listener B to be listening to Listener A instead of having both listening to the same object.  Basically it would be a chain.  Object changes and tells it's listeners (Listener A).  Listener A changes and tells it's listeners (Listener B).

Since B has a dependency on A that is where B should be listening.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions you can try is that the first event can be fired and reject value can be given to it. After that you can listen only once and from there and pass the actual data rejects to the subsequent jobs.

Comment: I don't understand how this wouldn't create more issues. 

First problem is "reject" usually means that the ListenerA didn't take any permanent action on the event. Perhaps "modified" would be a better word.

Second, this doesn't sound generalizable to networks of sources, listeners, and sinks. The order of handlers would have to be in the correct order. Better to have ListenerB listen to ListenerA if B is going to use something A computes.